# Correct Glue for Foam Outsulation?

Tags: insulation, exterior, adhesive

My house is masonry block about halfway up and then wood siding with top.  Two months ago I had outsulation installed.  It’s made up of 2x4 feet foam panels that are 2 inches thick.  These are covered by a plastic mesh in a scratch coat overlaid with a stucco like finish.  The outsulation works well and looks even better.
My problem is I’m not sure how to re-attach the address numbers.  I have 5 x 2 x 1/8 an inch address numbers that were screwed into the wood siding with three-quarter inch wood screws.
What I was thinking to do is to drill about an 1/8 inch hole through the stucco into the foam board and glue in the screws.  What I don’t know is what kind of glue would hold metal screws into a foam board.
Any ideas of what kind glue to use?  Or an even better idea on how to attach the numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a light touch on the screws you will be able to attach the numbers. Drill the surface with a slightly smaller bit than the threads, not the shank of the screws. An 1/8" bit may be the right size... Run the screws in and if you like put a small dab of clear caulk behind the number to seal the screw to the number and the screw to the hole so water may not get in. As light as the numbers are, the screws will keep the numbers at the right elevation and spacing and the way the caulk will hold, the numbers will stay until somebody removes them.

Comment: Do think a longer screw, maybe inch, would be better?  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Length, in this case will not matter, it will be what little grip you will get from the threads if the screw engaging into the stucco finish. The amount of caulk needed, just to clarify, will only need to be applied to the screw after it is started in the hole. The amount needed will be smaller than you expect. A drop the size of a pencil eraser will be much too big, unless the texture of the wall is really coarse. If it is only a sanded finish, half the size of a pencil eraser will do at each screw location. Use clear so if it goes out beyond the edges, it will not be a problem

Answer (score 0):

I would not suggest mounting the letters you have directly to the stucco finish. There may be another place where it would be appropriate to mount the numbers such as a fence, door, etc.

If the best place is on your home where they used to be, then you may want to consider getting an address plaque that you can mount them to. There are many different designs, sizes, etc. that might work for you.

Once the letters are mounted on the plaque, then you can screw the plaque directly to the wall. Since you say the foam is 2" thick, plus there is a parge coat over it, it will be approx 2 1/8" to get to solid wood. Based on those measurements plus the plaque itself, you would need 4" screws to ensure that it would be mounted solidly.

I would suggest pre-drilling the holes to make sure they are in the right place, and using a level to make the plaque sits straight. Another thing you would want to do is put a small dab of caulk on the hole and the tip of the screw before you install it. That will have the least amount of impact on your insulation. Also, when tightening the screws, make sure they aren't over-tightened. Over tightening the screws could crack the insulation and the mortar.